# add horizontal space like TAB

Tags: tables

I have two words separate by space in each line
I can have a tabular environment with two cell but I'm wondering if is there (in latex) a command like the `tab`in every word processor.

TIA

Renato

Comment: Are you familiar with the `tabbing` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `tabto`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
 {\flushleft\TabPositions{#1}}
 {\endflushleft}

\begin{document}

Some text for context Some text for context Some text for context
Some text for context Some text for context Some text for context
\begin{tabs}{2cm,4cm}
abcde\tab abcde\tab xyz \\
abcdef\tab abcdef\tab xyzuv \\
abcd\tab abcde\tab xyz
\end{tabs}
Some text for context Some text for context Some text for context
Some text for context Some text for context Some text for context

\end{document}
```

[image]